# request.exception is always null

Tags: grails, exception

I've created the following class

```
class ErrorsController {
   def index = {
      log.error request.exception
   }
}
```

In my UrlMappings I have this:

```
"500"(controller: "errors")
"404"(controller: "errors")
```

request.exception is always null.  Debugging, I see 2 parameters in the request object.  controller and action.  I see no exception.  If I remove the "404", it works as expected.  I'm using Grails 1.3.7.

Comment: Have you tried switching the two url mappings? 404 first then 500.
(Damn enter for save) -- and also, try having separate actions for 404 and 500 and specify action: "index" and action: "notFound" for example and see if problem persists.

Comment: Any progress with your exception problem?

Comment: Just tried your suggestions. Neither of which worked.  The only way to get the exception is to have a single error handler in the URL Mappings.  Order doesn't matter, and individual methods don't matter.